# Using ngFileUpload with Cloudinary

Tags: angularjs, cloudinary, ng-file-upload

I am trying to integrate the Cloudinary upload parameters(?) into the ngFileUpload function. The [function can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/xxo3sk41/590/) and allows a user to upload, and then drop an image on the page.  I am trying to get that functionality to work, but instead of uploading the way ngFileUpload says, to try to get it to upload the way Cloudinary says.

My Controller:

```
$scope.upload = function (dataUrl, name2) {
                console.log("name2", dataUrl);
               Upload.upload({
                   url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                   data: {
                       file: Upload.dataUrltoBlob(dataUrl, name2)
                   },
               }).then(function (response) {
                   $timeout(function () {
                       $scope.result2 = response.data;
                       console.log($scope.result2);
                   });
               }, function (response) {
                   if (response.status > 0) $scope.errorMsg = response.status
                       + ': ' + response.data;
                       console.log($scope.errorMsg);
               }, function (evt) {
                   $scope.progress2 = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
               });
           }
```

My Template:

```
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form name="myForm">
              <div class="uploadText">Crop Image and Upload</div>
              <i class="material-icons" style="position: relative; bottom: 28px; left:718px; cursor: pointer;" ng-click="vm.closeModal()">close</i>
              <hr class="add-horizontal-line">
              <br><br>
              <div ngf-select ng-model="picFile" accept="image/*" class="buttn" style="cursor: pointer;width: 200px; position: relative; left: 295px;">
                  <p style="position: relative; right: 10px; bottom: 3px;">Select Picture</p>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div ngf-drop ng-model="picFile" ngf-pattern="image/*"
                   class="cropArea" style="position: relative; left: 150px;">
                  <img-crop image="picFile  | ngfDataUrl"
                  result-image="croppedDataUrl" ng-init="croppedDataUrl=''" >
                  </img-crop>
              </div>
              <br><br>
              <div class="buttn" style="cursor: pointer; position: relative; left: 295px; bottom:16px;" ng-click="upload(croppedDataUrl, picFile.name2)"><p style="position: relative; left: 29px;">SUBMIT</p></div>

              <span ng-show="result2">Upload Successful</span>
              <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
          </form>
        </div>
        <footer style="background-color: RGBA(211,211,211,0.2); height: 75px; ">
          <div class="buttn" style="cursor: pointer; position: relative; left: 75%; top: 12px;"><p style="margin-left: 35px;" ng-click="vm.closeModal()">DONE</p></div>
        </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

The cloudinary function:

```
cloudinary.upload(file, {upload_preset: 'dbyhcyty'})
```

Is it possible to combine these two, so that the crop function of ngfileupload runs, and then uploads to cloudinary?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
      $scope.upload = function (dataUrl, name2) {
            console.log("name2", dataUrl);
            cloudinary.upload(dataUrl, {upload_preset: 'dhjgcyty'})
            .then(function(response){
              $scope.result = response.data;
              console.log($scope.result);
            });
        }
```